# How to stream print stream to textarea in javafx?

Tags: java, stream, javafx

I have a program with a function to get its stream of system.out.

```
 public PrintStream getStream() {
    final PrintStream origout = System.out;

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            origout.write(b);
        }
    }));
    return origout;
}
```

Now i want to display it in textarea of javafx scene which is in other class. Is it possible or do i have to use a lable for it?

Comment: what do you mean by lable?

Comment: Pardon me, I meant label.

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem adding text to a JavaFX TextArea compared to using a label. Call TextArea.appendText (String string)

Or setText (String string) if you want to set the whole text.

Hope this helps!